# mysqli_result::fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given

Tags: php

I get strange PHP warning in one function. It works in development environment, but fails in production environment.

> [18-Nov-2015 08:14:20 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  mysqli_result::fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in \NA1\BACKOFFICE\backoffice\applications\work\php\workAdmin.class.php on line 1093

and in my code I have

```
$res = $this->conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date_work) FROM `work` WHERE disposable_day = 1");
$resultSet = $res->fetch_all(MYSQL_NUM);
```

The same construction is used at many other places and it works, but suddenly fails here.

Both development and production environments have the same stack  Apache 2.4.10 + PHP 5.5.15

PS. of course, I can easily fix it by removing MYSQL_NUM (dont' ask me why it actually used here, it's old legacy app and I simply don't know) but, I wondering why MYSQL_NUM constant can have string type?

Comment: You are using mysqli to connect, and suddenly use a MYSQL function, that's a bad idea.

Comment: you are missing the execute function before calling `fetch_all` `$res->execute`

Comment: Epodax, It's not me, it have been here for many years =D

Comment: Basheer, no, you don't need need execute function when you use mysqli::query

Comment: Epodax, i removed it already, but i can't understand this behavior, that's reason why I ask )

Comment: The string type of the constant _may_ result from the fact that _maybe_ php tries to interpret it as a constant, which is not defined at that location and thus tries to treat it as string which you _maybe_ don't realize because you have switched off warnings.... (This is all so vague because you don't show your real code, but just some method calls...)

Comment: Arkascha, bingo! mysql extension enabled for test environment, but disabled for production where only mysqli is enabled, thats reason why MYSQL_NUM is treated as string. Case closed.

Comment: Timur, the fact that the `mysql-not-i` extension is disabled on the production environment is a Good Thing(tm). Do NOT change that, fix the code instead.

Comment: RandomSeed, yes, I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MYSQL_NUM`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php) constant is defined by the old, long-deprecated, soon-to-disappear [`mysql` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). If it is not present on your environment, then the `MYSQL_NUM` expression evaluates as `(string) "MYSQL_NUM"`.

Your error message indicates that your code actually uses the [`mysqli` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php). `mysqli::fetch_all()` does indeed take an integer parameter, and the code should read `$res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);` (notice the `I` in [`MYSQLI_NUM`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php)).

Unfortunately for you, both `MYSQL_NUM` and `MYSQLI_NUM` exist and evaluate to the same integer value on all previous systems so the error went unnoticed until today.